# std::ostream object in class is "not accessible through a pointer or object"

Tags: c++, c++11, iostream, ostream

I use several functions in a class, which are passed an ostream via the function interface, which in turn can be used to output error messages. I had hoped to be able to bind all ostreams to a single object that I then redirect to a file if necessary.

The relevant parts of my code look something like this:

```
#include <iostream>

class Example
{
    public:
    Example(){} //<--Error: "std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::basic_ostream() [with _CharT=char, _Traits=std::char_traits<char>]" (declared at line 390 of "/usr/include/c++/9/ostream") is inaccessible C/C++(330)

    void DoSomething()
    {
        FunctionWithOstream(out);
    }

    private:
    std::ostream out; //in my case, the ostream is currently not needed for the time being.

    void FunctionWithOstream(std::ostream& out)
    {
        out << "Something";
    }
};
```

At the first curly bracket of the constructor (or all constructors in the program) I get the following error message:

> protected function "std::basic_ostream<_CharT,
> _Traits>::basic_ostream() [with _CharT=char, _Traits=std::char_traits]" (declared at line 390 of "/usr/include/c++/9/ostream") is not accessible through a
> "std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits>" pointer or
> objectC/C++(410)

or for the short excample code i pasted here:

> "std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::basic_ostream() [with
> _CharT=char, _Traits=std::char_traits]" (declared at line 390 of "/usr/include/c++/9/ostream") is inaccessibleC/C++(330)

I hope the question is clear enough and thank you in advance for your time.

Greetings
Tillman

Comment: `std::ostream` is not  default constructible, you probably want reference/pointer instead.

Comment: If it's not currently needed then just delete it until it is needed. At that point it will be clearer what you have to do (which is constuct it in some way, or use a different type).

Comment: @Jarod42 How would that look like? I can't do much regarding the function interface, as there are some functions that use ostream and these in turn also call functions from other headers that have ostream in the interface.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`std::ostream` is not default constructible, you probably want reference/pointer instead:

```
class Example
{
public:
    Example(std::ostream& out = std::cout) : out(out) {}

    void DoSomething() { FunctionWithOstream(out); }

private:
    std::ostream& out;

    void FunctionWithOstream(std::ostream& os) { os << "Something"; }
};
```

Comment: I'd change `FunctionWithOstream` so that it doesn't have a parameter that hides a member

Comment: @Caleth: indeed, was from OP as excuse ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I have found a solution:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

class Example
{
    public:
    Example(){} //<--Error: "std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::basic_ostream() [with _CharT=char, _Traits=std::char_traits<char>]" (declared at line 390 of "/usr/include/c++/9/ostream") is inaccessible C/C++(330)

    void DoSomething()
    {
        FunctionWithOstream(outStream);
    }

    private:
    std::ostringstream outStream; //std::ostringstream instead of std::ostream is working fine.

    void FunctionWithOstream(std::ostream& out)
    {
        out << "Something";
    }
};
```

instead of std::ostream std::ostringstream can be used to receive the functions streams.